# MySQL, count the number of "filled" fields in a table

Tags: php, mysql, count

MySQL (table):

```
+----+------+
| id | text |
+----+------+
| 1  |      |
+----+------+
| 2  | blah |
+----+------+
| 3  |      |
+----+------+
| 4  | blah |
+----+------+
| 5  | blah |
+----+------+
```

PHP:

```
$a = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count1 FROM `table`");
$b = mysql_fetch_assoc($a);

echo $b['count1'];
```

Output:

```
5
```

However, I also want to count the **text fields** which are **filled** - within the same query, if possible.

Result:

```
5 in total
3 with filled text fields
```

Comment: When there is a blank is it NULL or "" ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total`, SUM(IF(`text` <> "",1,0)) AS `non_empty` FROM `table`
```

Comment: +1 But, do you know how the query-plan for this stacks up vs. something like Charles's answer (is the sum smart enough to pull out to an index if possible, for instance)? What about using a union?

Comment: @pst This is probably a new question by itself. Honestly, I can only speculate. But since all conditions (except in `HAVING`) are optimized for indeces, I'd think indeces are used. Someone should probably just compare @Charles' query and mine...

Comment: I would also like to see a comparison, considering I have only taken an Oracle SQL 11g course at my community college.

Comment: @pst @Charles I did the comparison and it turns out, that Charles' answer is actually the faster one. The subquery is optimized, whereas in my answer, the `IF` statement is not optimized and executed for each and every row to later sum up either `0` or `1` to the desired value.

Answer (score 4):

This can be accomplished quite nicely with sub-queries.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS id, COUNT(SELECT text FROM 'table' WHERE text IS NOT NULL) AS t FROM 'table'
```

Note to self: start proofreading your work before submitting it.

Comment: Downvote wasn't mine, but your original answer was wrong. You've since edited it though.

Comment: I gave you an upvote. But you have to promise that runs as advertised on MySQL (I don't use MySQL). Otherwise, give yourself two down-votes :p

Comment: I think they downvoted because "Count(text)" wouldn't have worked ..I think

Comment: Removed my downvote. The initial answer was just wrong, though.

Comment: @gore I guess I didn't see the downvote until after I edited, my mistake.

Comment: @Charles No problem. You even got a +1 from me for initiating some sort of speculation (see the comments on my answer).