# Get total number of filled row in table in SQLite

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

My Question is Similar to [MySQL, count the number of "filled" fields in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730370/mysql-count-the-number-of-filled-fields-in-a-table)

But i can not got my proper solution. How is it possible in Sqlite?

I Know about get using for loop. but i want to get by query.

Please help me on this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Instead of referencing another question, please update your question to stand on its own. This makes it easier for everyone looking at your question and will help of the other question is ever delete for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query like this will work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from raw where rawData <> '' AND rawData IS NOT NULL
```

This assumes there is a table called "raw" and the column you're checking against is "rawData"

Comment: But please Explain, what is use of <> 'operator' in this Query ?

Comment: <> is the "does not equal" operator for sqlite. See this link for a full list of operators: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_operators.htm